# HP laptop bootlooping

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, hp-laptop

My laptop: HP STREAM with Windows 10

I was trying to free up space on the tiny 28GB C: drive and must have done something stupid.

When powering up, the HP logo appears as usual, but then the screen goes black. A few seconds later, the HP logo reappears - then black.  This continues over and over.

I did not create a System Image or Recovery Disc when I bought this notebook 4 years ago, **but** I have backups on a separate USB drive along with a "copy" of the entire 28GB C Drive.

I have another new HP Stream for which I made a System Image and Recovery disc.

**My question**:  How can I first rescue the old HP from this bootloop and then restore the machine to a functioning tool?  My knowledge and skills are low to medium.

**Note**: A computer tech said that a partition on the C drive was "corrupted".

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if it can boot into safe mode.

Start your PC in safe mode in Windows 10:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode

If it can’t, I think you’d better to do an in-place upgrade.

How to perform an In-place Upgrade with Windows 10 Step-by-Step Guide:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-perform-an-in-place-upgrade-with-windows-10/7f0b236e-3c6c-4913-9691-c4baa2a6190a

If it can boot into safe mode, you could use Windows Startup Repair.

How To Repair Windows 10:
https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/repair-windows-10

Comment: Boot loop problem solved by repeatedly hitting f11.  Then, on a working computer, going to "Windows 10 media creation tool" I downloaded Windows 10 onto a reformatted USB stick [8 GB & TIME required].  I was then able to install a new version of Windows 10 using the stick after formatting [clearing the corrupted system] the 28GB drive on the HP Stream.

Comment: To be clear: The link by "How To Repair Windows 10" from Circle_F tells the story well at solution #5 EXCEPT in my case, I needed to create the media on a USB flash drive because I was not updating Windows 10, but starting from scratch after formatting the computer's drive so there was room for the complete installation.  Phew.  A tech shop said this would cost over $300 to fix.  I managed, with a little trial & error, to do it myself in 3-4 hours.